# Correct parallelisation of git filter-branch

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I have a repo with loads of branches and "git filter-branch ... -- --all" dramatically slows down by and by (approx. 400,000 commits, approx. runtime 7 days). But 'git filter-branch' on a single branch gives a significant performance boost (approx. 5 days).

Is it correct to use the following algorithm to parallelize 'filter-branch' on loads of  branches?

1. for bx (B1..Bn) do: git clone --bare -b bx repo.orig repo.bx
2. parallelize over repo.bx: git filter-branch --index-filter ... -- HEAD
3. git init --bare repo.new
4. for bx (B1..Bn) do: cd repo.bx; git push repo.new HEAD:bx

Rregards, Gert

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations on finding an interesting way to parallelise the execution of `git filter-branch` - I think in principle, the procedure you've described *would* succeed in giving a correct & internally-consistent re-written history, though that would definitely depend on precisely *what* your `--index-filter` command was doing (the resulting branch histories would appear completely separate if you were doing something crazy like inserting random numbers into files, for instance).

`git filter-branch` is a *very* powerful tool: **It allows you to perform completely arbitrary operations against *each & every* file and commit in your history** - and though that flexibility sounds appealing, it often works against you - you pay a *heavy* price in execution time for it. So the question is- do you need that flexibility? Could you be more specific in your question about what you're trying to achieve?

### [The BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), an alternative to git filter-branch...

As of Git v1.9, the [documentation notes for `git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_notes) contain this advice (admittedly contributed by myself, but vetted by the Git mailing list!):

> git-filter-branch allows you to make complex shell-scripted rewrites
>   of your Git history, but you probably don't need this flexibility if
>   you're simply removing unwanted data like large files or passwords.
>   For those operations you may want to consider [The BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), a
>   JVM-based alternative to git-filter-branch, typically at least 10-50x
>   faster for those use-cases, and with quite different characteristics

The BFG  can perform many of the tasks that `git filter-branch` is used for - but does so **much** faster - in part because it uses memoization, but also because it performs parallelisation of the cleaning tasks, allowing it to take full advantage of multi-core machines. These factors combine to make an execution time saving rather better than the 30% reduction you might possibly get from parallelising the `filter-branch` runs - in fact, the run-time reduction is often much closer to 98%, a *50x* speed-up or above.

[A comment by Elliot Glaysher](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#feedback), Google engineer working on Google Chrome:

> I was able to shrink the current repository down to ~500 megabytes in
>   about 10 minutes when using this tool. My hand crafted scripts clock
>   in at 615 megabytes in 3 days time for comparison.

All told, it's worth considering whether The BFG could be a better tool for the job.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: Unfortunately I want to remove many pathes within the repository. BFG isn't able to do that because it deletes folders (given by name).

Comment: Fair enough - just to get a better idea of your needs, are you removing those multiple paths in order to a) reduce overall repo size in MB, b) remove/replace private data or c) to acheive or directory-structure reorganisation? - in general, the BFG can do the first two, but doesn't currently support the third.

Comment: It's the case c). I want to seperate the repo into different development topics. Of course this also reduces the size of the separated repos.